# Rollover gallery images appear over my fixed header when animating

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a fixed div header. A header that stays at the top of the page when scrolling up/down.

```
#top {
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
background-image: url(layout/bannerbg.png);
background-size: 100% 100%;
height: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 6px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 6px #000;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 6px #000;
}
```

On my page that conatins my image gallery, the gallery images use a jQuery rollover, fade in/out effect. During the fade in/out, the image briefly appears on top of my fixed header. Anyone know a quick fix for this?

Comment: Does that happen every time? If you load an image and that happens, will it happen again the second time you load the image?

Comment: try adding an z-index:9999; for #top

Comment: The "z-index: 9999; worked. Thanks a bunch max li.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
#top{
    z-index:100;
    /*other css code for #top*/
}
```